# Writing a method which select all the rows and columns of the table given using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to write a general method which returns all the columns and rows (the entire table)  and it has to be general so it must work with every table you pass as an argument.

For example there is table in the database `dbo.Media` and the method must take it as an argument (which the most important part of question is how) and return something that can be used as an alternative to `select * from dbo.media` also
it must be general so whenever I created the new table I pass  the name to the method and it does its job.

Comment: I think the author asks for something like this `db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM tableName")`

Comment: Seems that your professor is promoting sql injection, but anyway, look at the data type of youth query. It's a string. So your parameter needs also to be a string...

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: Actually you did not ask "how to pass the dbset to a method" I read your post, didn't see it. You asked how to make it general for every table. And your method does this almost exactly. You just need to fix the syntactical error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you write this method on the `DbContext` class?

Then you could write something like in a separate new class file (e.g. `ActionContextExtensions.cs` or something like that):

```
public partial class ActionContext : DbContext
{
    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll<T>() where T: class
    {
        return this.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

This returns the type as defined by the generic parameter - so you can say something like:

```
var result = db.SelectAll<Employee>()
```

or

```
var result = db.SelectAll<Customer>()
```

or

```
var result = db.SelectAll<Book>()
```

Comment: @mjwills: a generic `IEnumerable` is the "smallest" possible type you can have - it has no "link" to Entity Framework (as the `DbSet<T>` does, which the `.Set<T>()` method returns natively). You *could* of course directly return the `DbSet<T>` - but then you have a strong coupling to Entity Framework - that's what I was trying to avoid

Answer (score -1):

Something like this.. You need to provide class or use dynamic

```
    public T[] ActionContext<T>(sql)
    {
        using (var db = new ActionContext())
        {
            return  db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql).ToArray();
        }
    }
```